# Regular expression for both length with whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression with following conditions.

1. Allow empty at any position in string.
2. First three are characters-range (1-3)
3. Next six are numeric (must) -range (6)
4. Next optional to have characters - range (1-3)
5. After that optional to have numeric - range(0-2)

For this i tried lot of things nothing works.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{0,2}
```

This expression works fine for matching all criteria but it is not allowing empty strings. Thanks in advance.

I just want to validate the string like "AB 123456 ADF 12". 
As i mentioned first point the string contains empty space at any position in given string like "AB 123 456 ADF 12".

Comment: Make whole thing optional and add `$` anchor: `^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{0,2})?$`. If empty strings means a string with no characters or spaces only do this: `^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{0,2}|\s*)$`

Comment: Thanks for reply. but this was not allowing empty space between the charactes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your pattern in parentheses and make it optional using `?`:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

- `^` Assert beginning of string
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{0,2}` Your pattern
- `)?` End of NCG, optional
- `$` Assert end of string

If you want to match strings with whitespace characters add `\\s` (or `\s` treating literal) and remove `?`:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{0,2}|\s*)$
                                                ^^^^
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/LKqL9r/1)

### Update

Based on comment:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z](?:\s*[a-zA-Z]){0,2}\s*\d(?:\s*\d){5}(?:\s*[a-zA-Z](?:\s*[a-zA-Z]){0,2})?\s*(?:\d\s*\d?)?)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/LKqL9r/3)

Comment: this regular expression is not allowing me to enter spaces between the characters or numerics

Comment: What input string you would like to be matched by regex?

Comment: I want to validate A 123456 ABC 12

Comment: Is only one space allowed between each pattern or it could be multiple? like `A____123456`

Comment: I was trying to validate multiple spaces too

Comment: and do you want to match `A 12 345 6 ABC 12` as well?

Comment: Try this [`^(?:[a-zA-Z](?:\s*[a-zA-Z]){0,2}\s*\d(?:\s*\d){5}(?:[a-zA-Z](?:\s*[a-zA-Z]){0,2})?\s*(?:\d\s*\d?)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/LKqL9r/2)

Comment: this expression fails to validate  "ab 123456 abc 12" String